# Android eclipse giving errors out

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I'm having some problems I had gotten a Eclipse that had worked for Android Development installed the SDK and everything and I try to run my APP and it says there is still errors in your code.
So I look down and these are the errors I got:

```
[2016-02-04 15:47:07 - BibleSearch1] Found 2 versions of
android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, [2016-02-04 15:47:07 -
BibleSearch1] but not all the versions are identical (check is based
on SHA-1 only at this time). [2016-02-04 15:47:07 - BibleSearch1] All
versions of the libraries must be the same at this time. [2016-02-04
15:47:07 - BibleSearch1] Versions found are: [2016-02-04 15:47:07 -
BibleSearch1] Path:
C:\Users\shiyloh2\workspace\BibleSearch1\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2016-02-04 15:47:07 - BibleSearch1]    Length: 1364299 [2016-02-04
15:47:07 - BibleSearch1]    SHA-1:
b6c138ba72ce38beda559df33d369856854fd6f5 [2016-02-04 15:47:07 -
BibleSearch1] Path:
C:\Users\shiyloh2\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2016-02-04 15:47:07 - BibleSearch1]    Length: 758727 [2016-02-04
15:47:07 - BibleSearch1]    SHA-1:
efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507 [2016-02-04 15:47:07 -
BibleSearch1] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies [2016-02-04 15:47:12
BibleSearch1] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing [2016-02-04 15:47:15 -
BibleSearch1] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the
dependency list, [2016-02-04 15:47:15 - BibleSearch1] but not all the
versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2016-02-04 15:47:15 - BibleSearch1] All versions of the libraries
must be the same at this time. [2016-02-04 15:47:15 - BibleSearch1]
Versions found are: [2016-02-04 15:47:15 - BibleSearch1] Path:
C:\Users\shiyloh2\workspace\BibleSearch1\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2016-02-04 15:47:15 - BibleSearch1]    Length: 1364299 [2016-02-04
15:47:15 - BibleSearch1]    SHA-1:
b6c138ba72ce38beda559df33d369856854fd6f5 [2016-02-04 15:47:15 -
BibleSearch1] Path:
C:\Users\shiyloh2\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2016-02-04 15:47:15 - BibleSearch1]    Length: 758727 [2016-02-04
15:47:15 - BibleSearch1]    SHA-1:
efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507 [2016-02-04 15:47:15 -
BibleSearch1] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies [2016-02-04 15:47:16
BibleSearch1] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing [2016-02-04 15:47:23 -
BibleSearch1] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find
attribute android:preserveIconSpacing [2016-02-04 15:51:29 -
BibleSearch1] ERROR: In <declare-styleable> MenuView, unable to find
attribute android:preserveIconSpacing
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
right click project -> properties->android, change the API level.

ERROR: In  MenuView, unable to find XXX usually because the API change.